# create smaller tables from a larger table based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a large table which I wanna create some tables based on the data of the large table but I don't wanna change the large table.

consider the schema of large table:

Person(id, Fname, Lname, ssn, role)

role: the role of person can be: manager, teacher and student.

now I want 3 smaller tables based on the role of persons. 
Teacher(id, Fname, Lname, ssn)

Student(id, Fname, Lname, ssn)

Manager(id, Fname, Lname, ssn)

I am looking for a query like below but I don't know the correct syntax.

```
select *
case 
        when P.role = 'student' then insert into Student(id, Fname, Lname, ssn) values (P.id, P.Fname, P.Lname, P.ssn)
        when P.role = 'teacher' then ...
        when P.role = 'manager' then ...
end
from person as P
```

note: ... notation means the query is same as the Student query with altering in table name.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate inserts for each table:

```
insert into student ( id, Fname, Lname, ssn )
    select P.id, P.Fname, P.Lname, P.ssn
    from person p
    where p.role = 'student';
```

And so on.

Or, just use views:

```
create view v_students as
    select P.id, P.Fname, P.Lname, P.ssn
    from person p
    where p.role = 'student';
```